# why is audioRecorderDidFinishRecording not getting called? Able to record and play audio successfully

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avfoundation

In the [code here](http://pastebin.com/BbeswQRe), I am able to record audio and also play it back successfully no problem there.

Problem is that  `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` is never getting called. What am I  missing?

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
    println("Recording finished")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to call audioRecorder.stop() first

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning self to delegate even before it is created

```
audioRecorder?.delegate = self

audioPlayer?.delegate = self

prepareForRecording()
```

`audioRecorder` is created in `prepareForRecording()` function, `audioRecorder` is nil before that.

Assign self to delegate after it is created.